# Prevent final LF / CRLF when writing a text file

Tags: sas

Am delivering some data to a client app (via STP) that is complaining about an additional blank line.  I can fix (remove) this on the client side, but curious to know if a fix is possible within SAS.

The issue is that when generating a text file, SAS always adds a final carriage return (of a type configurable via the `termstr` option) on the last record.  For example:

```
data _null_;
  file "C:\Temp\test.csv";
  set sashelp.class;
  put (_all_) ('09'x);
run;
```

and

```
PROC EXPORT DATA=sashelp.class 
  OUTFILE="C:\Temp\test2.csv"
  DBMS=TAB REPLACE;
  PUTNAMES=NO;
run;
```

generate:

[image]

and

[image]

respectively.

How do I generate a file that does not contain the additional blank line (record 20 in the above images)?

*Note that my text file is actually being streamed via the _webout fileref, so I don't have the option to read it back into SAS.*

Comment: Just to quibble a bit, I don't think there is really a blank line in your csv file.  It's just that there is a CR/LF at the end of line 19.  So you want to a way to have CR/LF on every line except the last line, correct?  Interesting question.  I've never had this cause a problem...

Comment: I'll take that!  Yes, the problem is just like you say - I want a way to avoid writing the CR/LF on the final record.  My client app is actually excel, it connects via a web query, and a third party tool then reads the (unformatted) data and complains about a blank record.  I will use VBA to remove, but it must be possible to avoid that final newline character!

Comment: I would push back to the consumer that they are interpreting the end-of-line characters incorrectly.  They are acting like they are beginning of line characters.  Why don't they require them at the start of the first record?

Comment: Did you try using TERMSTR=LF or TERMSTR=CR?  Perhaps the consumer is just confused by the DOS convention of using CRLF to mark the end of the line?

Comment: @Tom - the initial 'consumer' is Excel, and I confirmed that the VBA UsedRange incorporates the blank line :-/

Comment: @Tom - fyi, the TERMSTR option does not have an effect on the existence of the final end of line marker.

Comment: How is excel consuming the file? When I open a normal CSV file (with end of line characters on the last line) it does not insert an extra blank line into my spreadsheet.

Comment: via a web query (Data / Get External Data / From Web)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roll your own.  However my put (_ALL) places an extra comma at the end of each "line" so you end up with an extra blank space in the last field which may or may not be a problem.

```
data _null_;
   file "~/testeof.csv" dsd recfm=n;
   set sashelp.class(obs=5) end=eof;
   put (_all_)(:) +(-1) @;
   if not eof then put '0d0a'x;
   else put '20'x;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: How about writing an end of file character ('1A'x) instead of a space at the end of the file?

Comment: @Tom I tried that but SAS/PROC IMPORT saw that character as data, which caused the last field to be interpreted by PROC IMPORT as character.

Comment: Works a treat!  Thanks!